# Tomcat doesn't produce Heap Dump when OutOfMemory

Tags: eclipse, out-of-memory, tomcat7, heap-dump

Since I am investigating some OOM issue, I'd like Tomcat to generate a HeapDump every time that it hits an OOM. I am aware that I can do it with jmap and visualvm but I'd rather Tomcat to generate it automatically. I setup the following Java options with no success:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\sts-bundle"
```

I am using Spring Tool Suite (a.k.a. STS)

```
Version: 3.9.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201712210947
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)
```

The embedded Tomcat is Tomcat 7.

Please advise.

Comment: Perhaps the user running tomcat has no permissions on that directory. Try setting a directory inside tomcat root.

Comment: Good guess but I tried to do that already and that's not the case.

Comment: Make sure JAVA_OPTS is correctly set by inspecting the tomcat process command string (not sure how to do that on windows though). Also, if tomcat tried to make the dump but couldn't, there should be an error on log files.